# How to cover this gas line sticking out of the wall?

Tags: electrical, plumbing, gas, basement-refinishing

I'm looking for nice a way to cover this gas line plug sticking out of my wall. It's an eyesore that is no longer needed, I believe a leftover from the oven in an extra basement kitchen area. It sticks out about 0.75" from the wall.

I know they make domed cover plates for plumbing cleanouts (such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009Y9ZYRW)), but those typically screw right into a plastic cleanout plug. In this case, it's a metal plug/cap. Ideally I was hoping to find something similar (domed blank cover plate) that I can screw into the wall with wall anchors. I'm not really sure what I should be searching for though. Any suggestions?

[image: Gas line]

Comment: depending on the fitting inside the wall you may be able to tighten the connector so that it is behind the wall. You'll need to open the wall to get a wrench on it.

Answer (score 3):

I think if you remove the plug and replace it with a **flush plug**, then spackle the crack around it and paint. It would (IMO) be less obtrusive than a cover.

[image]

Comment: Yep this will make it flush

Answer (score 2):

How about a surface mount double gang electric outlet box and a blank cover plate over it. Trim a hole in the back of the box to fit the pipe.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Usually if you are a gas customer your gas company will do this for free (the one I use did- I had no idea- I had asked the gas man whom to call to remove them and he told me it was a service they provided for free), all you have to do is ask. I had 2 lines removed from inside the house because we no longer use the natural gas heaters that were here before we bought our house. The drywall fix , of course, is your responsibility to fix, but I was so glad to get them gone, so I didn't mind.